# Why use the global keyword in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces, global

I would like to understand why you might want to use the `global::` prefix. In the following code, ReSharper is identifying it as redundant, and able to be removed:

[image]

Comment: It's a namespace, not a keyword.

Comment: So why would I use it? Resharper is telling me it's not needed, but Microsoft's code generation uses it. I'm trying to understand where I would ever use it. Thanks

Comment: @John, Just curious - trying to learn why it's used by the code-gen process.

Comment: @Paul: do not edit generated code. Not even in ReSharper. Generated code is a lot like sausage - you don't want to know what's in there.

Comment: @John, I'm not editing generated code, just trying to understand what it's doing. I have some code generation processes I'm working on, so I'd like to understand what others are doing any why.

Comment: Paul clearly wants to be a answerer at SO some day.  Go Paul!

Comment: @John-Saunders Telling someone to ignore their curiosity is horrible advice. How exactly do you expect anyone to learn? @Paul-Fryer I think this is a great question - I've often wondered the same thing myself but haven't gotten around to asking.

Comment: @John - Not sure how to respond to your comment "don't you have better things to do with your time". This time is spent trying to become a better developer and programmer. I would ask you don't you have better things to do than leave pointless comments that don't help anyone?

Comment: Would the downvoter please leave a comment. Thanks.

Comment: Well said Paul. People like John, should be banned from access to community sites since comments like this highly demotivates the spirit of the others.

Comment: "curiosity and cats, keep it in mind. Don't you have better things to do with your time?"

That is the most idiotic comment I have ever seen on a question-and-answer forum.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

It is best to use the global namespace prefix in generated code. This is done to avoid situations where a similar named type exists in your namespace.

If you create a type named `System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute` **inside your namespace** you will notice that ReSharper no longer says that the `global::` is not needed. The code generator simply wants to avoid any collisions with the names of your own types.

Comment: Short,simple  and nice answer

Answer (score 67):

The keyword `global::` causes the compiler to bind names starting in the global namespace as opposed to in the current context.  It's needed in places where a bindable member exists in a given context that has the same name as a global one and the global one is desired.

For example

```
class Test {
  class System {}
  public void Example() {
    System.Console.WriteLine("here"); // Error since System binds to Test.System
    global::System.Console.WriteLine("here"); // Works
}
```

The corresponding MSDN page has a few more examples (including the one above)

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d.aspx

Answer (score 2):

> "The global contextual keyword, when it comes before the :: operator, refers to the global namespace, which is the default namespace for any C# program and is otherwise unnamed."

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc713620.aspx

Comment: Shami Qureshi, if you're going to copy an answer word-for-word, you need to at least mention the source. Although your answer really *doesn't* answer the question, I've edited it to include the URL which you copied it from.