# Globally defining a function in C#

Tags: c#, function, global, definition

I have two functions which I seem to be including in software quite a lot to convert strings and byte arrays between types. The usage is something like this:

```
string str = "Hello world";
byte[] b = strToByteArray(str);
```

Firstly, is there a way I can include this in the System namespace so I don't have to define it in code anymore?

Secondly, is there a way to define it as part of the string class, so the usage would be more like:

```
string str = "Hello world";
byte[] b = str.ToByteArray();
```

Comment: 1) Compile your commonly used utility methods into a DLL. 2) Reuse the DLL. 3) ???

Comment: Note that your function only makes sense given a specific encoding. _Beware the horrors of Unicode_!

Comment: Just make the method static....

Answer (score 7):

What you're asking for is provided in C# by [Extension Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).

Comment: Extension methods can only add instance methods to existing class. If you want a "near" global method (no instance), you have to create a class with static method

Comment: YOu could extend string and byte[] ;)

Comment: @SteveB Actually, you can call an extension method statically as well: `Extensions.MyExtension("some string")` instead of `"some string".MyExtension()`.  @TomTom `string` is `sealed`, and `byte[]` isn't valid as a base type, so no you can't do that.

Answer (score 4):

**Why aren't you using `System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes`?**

> Firstly, is there a way I can include this in the System namespace so I don't have to define it in code anymore?

I don't know what you mean by "define it in code anymore". You can add anything you want to `System`, but that's generally frowned upon. Just say

```
namespace System {
    // add classes here
}
```

C# doesn't have top-level methods like you seem to desire. [Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/22/why-doesn-t-c-implement-top-level-methods.aspx) has discussed this before.

> Secondly, is there a way to define it as part of the string class, so the usage would be more like:

I suppose that you could define an extension method on `string`:

```
public static class StringExtensions {
    public static byte[] GetBytes(this string s) {
        // do something and return byte[]
    }
}
```

If you want, put it in the namespace `System`. Again, this is generally frowned upon, and you still have to reference the assembly that contains the definition.

Comment: Thanks, extension methods are pretty much what I was after. By "define it in code anymore" I meant add it to the standard includes so I don't have to add it to every new project.

Answer (score 2):

Don't reinvent the wheel, Use **[Encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ds4kkd55.aspx)** class instead.

Answer (score 0):

1. No; C# does not support top-level functions
2. You're looking for extension methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can write an extension method for string that does what you need: 
http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/csharp-3.0/extension-methods/

and then you can just call it with every string:

```
byte[] b = "Hello world".ToByteArray();
```

for the implementation you can use Encoding.GetBytes by the way

Answer (score 0):

All you need is custom [Extension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) within namespace `System`.

```
namespace System
{
    public static class StringExtensions
    {
        public static byte[] ToByteArray(this string source)
        {
            // return result
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See [Why use the global keyword in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552763/why-use-global-keyword-in-net) for additional information... You can add a using statement to achieve the semantic you are looking for or you can use the global keyword.

Answer (score 0):

> Firstly, is there a way I can include this in the System namespace so I don't have to define it in 
>   code anymore?

??? What do you want?

System namespace? Put them into a (static) calass in the system namespace. Namespaces have NOTHING to do with assemblies, dll's etc. - you can use whatever you like.

Oterhwise, do what most people do - start a project with tools classes. I have some of them around that I use for common code.